# ScheduledExecutorService, how to stop action without stopping executor?

Tags: java, executors

I have this code:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutor;
.....
ScheduledFuture<?> result = scheduledExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
    new SomethingDoer(),0, measurmentPeriodMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

After some event I should stop action, which Declared in `run()` method of the `SomethingDoer`, which implements `Runnable`.

How can I do this? I can't shutdown executor, I should only revoke my periodic task. Can I use `result.get()` for this? And if I can, please tell me how it will work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `result.cancel()`. The `ScheduledFuture` is the handle for your task. You need to cancel this task and it will not be executed any more.

Actually, `cancel(boolean mayInterruptIfRunning)` is the signature and using it with `true` parameter will cause a currently running exection's thread to be interrupted with the `interrupt()` call. This will throw an interrupted exception if the thread is waiting in a blocking interruptible call, like `Semaphore.acquire()`. Keep in mind that `cancel` will ensure only that the task will not be executed any more once it stopped the execution.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`cancel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel%28boolean%29) method from your [`ScheduledFuture`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html) object. Once cancelled, no further tasks will be executed.

If you want your currently running task to stop, you need to code your `run` method so it is sensitive to interrupts and pass `true` to the `cancel()` method to request an interrupt.